# How to display an image from MongoDB database via PyMongo and Bottle?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, bottle, gridfs

**Desired Behaviour**

Upload an image to GridFS and then show it in the browser (just to get an idea of how GridFS works).

**Current Behaviour**

Image is uploaded to GridFS collections (I can access it via the shell) and then a 500 error is returned.

**Error**

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Sorry, the requested URL 'https:/mysite.com/form_action_path' caused an error:
```

**Form**

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="data" />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Bottle**

```
# relevant libraries
import gridfs
from bottle import response

@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    data = request.files.data
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(data.filename)
    if ext not in ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg'):
        return "File extension not allowed."
    if data and data.file:
        raw = data.file.read()
        filename = data.filename
        dbname = 'grid_files'
        db = connection[dbname]
        fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
        fs.put(raw,filename=filename)
        # this is the part where I am trying to get the image back out
        collection = db.fs.files
        cursor = collection.find_one({"filename":"download (1).jpg"})
        response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
        return cursor
    return "You missed a field."
```

**Edit:**

This returns an image in the browser:

```
        # .... same as above
        # this is the part where I am trying to get the image back out
        thing = fs.get_last_version(filename=filename)
        response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
        return thing
```

My remaining questions would be:

- Why doesn't the initial code work?
- How could I return the image back so that it could be used in an image tag?
- When the image is being returned, what exactly *is* being returned?  Binary data that the browser is interpreting?  Something else?
- And does the image consist of the merged `chunks` in the `data` field of the `fs.chunks` collection documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial code doesn't work because you're returning a document, which PyMongo represents as a Python dictionary. Flask doesn't know what to do with it. (Note that find_one() returns a single document, and find() returns a Cursor.)

Your final code returns the "thing" it gets from GridFS.get_last_version(), which is a [GridOut](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridOut) object for reading from a GridFS file.

GridOut is iterable: iterating a GridOut obtains chunks of byes. Flask **does** know how to turn an iterable into an HTTP response, so the second version of your code works.

The lesson is: when you want to interact with GridFS, use the GridFS class rather than find() or find_one().

Yes, the image consists of merged `chunks` data from the `fs.chunks` collection.

To include the image in an `<img>` tag, something like this should work:

```
@route('/images/<filename>')
def image(filename):
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    gridout = fs.get_last_version(filename=filename)
    response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
    return gridout
```

Then in your HTML, `<img src="/images/filename.jpg">`.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Earlier I put up a more specific question regarding the `<img>` tag implementation.  It follows the same logic as your suggestion above but it is returning a 404 for the image.  That question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117166/how-to-link-to-an-image-in-gridfs-in-an-img-tag