# How to link to an image in GridFS in an <img> tag?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, bottle, gridfs

> We can think about how serving a list of images works in HTML. When we
>   serve a page it includes  tags that reference an image and then
>   the browser makes a separate request to get each one. This works well
>   with mongodb. We can just serve the page and insert tags like `<img
>   src="/profile_pics/userid">` and then our server just redirects that
>   path to the GridFS file with `{"profile_pic": userid}`.

*Source*:  http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/mongodb.html

I have tried:

**HTML**

```
<li>
<img src="/static/img/gridfs/download.jpg">
</li>
```

**Bottle Route**

```
# relevant libraries
import gridfs
from bottle import response

@route('/static/img/gridfs/<filename>')
def server_gridfs_img(filename):
  dbname = 'grid_files'
  db = connection[dbname]
  fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
  thing = fs.get_last_version(filename=filename)
  response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
  return thing
```

**Error**

I get a 404 for `https://mysite.com/static/img/gridfs/download.jpg` - both when trying to access the image URL directly in a browser, and in the Firebug console error tab when loading the page.

**Edit:**

*Working Code*

```
@route('/gridfs/img/<filename>')
# OR @route('/gridfs/img/<filename:path>')
def server_gridfs_img(filename):
  dbname = 'grid_files'
  db = connection[dbname]
  fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
  thing = fs.get_last_version(filename=filename)
  response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
  return thing
```

Note: Using `static` instead of another word like `gridfs` caused the above not to work.  I don't know why.  All other routes had been commented out when testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me. First in the Python shell:

```
>>> import pymongo, gridfs
>>> db = pymongo.MongoClient().my_gridfs
>>> # Read a file I have put in the current directory.
>>> img_contents = open('image.jpg', 'rb').read()
>>> gridfs.GridFS(db).put(img_contents, filename='image.jpg')
ObjectId('52d6c182ca1ce955a9d60f57')
```

Then in app.py:

```
import gridfs
import pymongo
from bottle import route, run, template, response

connection = pymongo.MongoClient()

@route('/static/img/gridfs/<filename>')
def gridfs_img(filename):
    dbname = 'my_gridfs'
    db = connection[dbname]
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    thing = fs.get_last_version(filename=filename)
    response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
    return thing

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

When I visit `http://localhost:8080/static/img/gridfs/image.jpg` I see my image in the browser.

I notice you put "https://" in the example URL, are you using a Bottle plugin or a frontend server like Apache?

Comment: In order to redirect `http` to `https`, I am using the solution posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20311393/1063287.

Comment: Solution: I don't know why but using static in the context `/static/subdir1/subdir2/<filename>` caused the error. If I replaced `static` with any other word it was ok. I had commented out all other routes when testing this. I have added working code to OP.

Comment: Do you have Nginx or Apache fronting the server? Perhaps it already has a rule for "/static".